# Mura Setup not shows Mura Admin page

Tags: windows, apache, tomcat, lucee, mura

Mura setup is done as per documentation.

1. From Mura setup page not able to get Mura admin page
2. Setup gives some page where i can not go for other menu 
   [Mura Setup image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xR31Q.jpg)
3. the default button goes to Lucee welcome page
4. settings.ini has mode=production, indexfileinurls=0,siteidinurls=0 and
   recaptchalanguage=en
5. The system is  Windows 7, Apache2.4.18, MySQL5.7, Lucee Tomcat8 and  Lucee 4.5.2.018.

Why I did not get Mura Admin Page?

Answer (score 0):

After installation , http://domain.com/admin
  gives the admin login.