# Mura setup does not show Mura admin page, instead shows Lucee welcome page

Tags: tomcat, lucee, mura

Mura setup is done as per documentation

1. From Mura setup page, I am not able to access the Mura admin page
2. Setup gives the Lucee welcome page
   [image: Image of Set up page]
   Can anyone suggest how I might fix this?

Comment: No need to post the same question twice: [Mura Setup not shows Mura Admin page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36572376/mura-setup-not-shows-mura-admin-page). Voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

after installation
http://domain.com/admin gives me the expected page.